# regex equals to something exactly but does not equal to something else

Tags: regex

my regex query below does an exact match of a word say Bob or Bill for example

```
var regExp = new RegExp("^" + inputVal + "$", 'i');
```

what i want it to do is match anything exactly (Bob or Bill Etc) but not match Fred

so match anything exactly except for Fred, does that make sense?
anyone help me out as to how i do that?

Thanks

EDIT 2:
i thought id show my actual script instead, what im doing is searching a table, and im page load i want to hide rows that contain a string. so if exlucde lenght is greater than 0 hide that row...

```
function searchPagingTable(inputVal, tablename, fixedsearch, exclude) {
    var table = $(tablename);
    table.find('tr:not(.header)').each(function (index, row) {
        var allCells = $(row).find('td');
        if (allCells.length > 0) {
            var found = false;
            allCells.each(function (index, td) {
                if (fixedsearch == 1) {
                    var regExp = new RegExp("^" + inputVal + "$", 'i');
                }
                else if (exclude.length > 0)
                {
                    var regExp = new RegExp("^(?!" + exclude + ")", "i");
                }
                else {
                    var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
                }
                if (regExp.test($(td).text())) {
                    found = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if (found == true) $(row).show().removeClass('exclude'); else $(row).hide().addClass('exclude');
        }
    });
    pa
```

ginate();
}

Comment: Are you making sure that `inputVal` never contains any regex metacharacters like `|`?

Comment: Doesn't really makes sense. Do you mean matching literally anything except Fred?

Comment: Do you use Javascript ?

Comment: i want to exclude fred from a list, so i need a regex to exlude fred and show anything else

Comment: @AlexW Can you add an example of the list to your question ?

Comment: ive added my actual code, hopefully it will clear things up!

Answer (score 3):

That would be

```
var exclude = "Fred"
var regExp = new RegExp("^(?!.*" + exclude + ")", "i");
```

This regex matches any string except those that contain `Fred`. It doesn't actually match any characters in the string, but that's sufficient if you're just looking for a `true/false` result.

This will also find strings that contain `Alfred` or `Fredo`, so if you don't want that, you need to tell the regex only to look for entire words using [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
var regExp = new RegExp("^(?!.*\\b" + exclude + "\\b)", "i");
```

You need to make sure that your `exclude` string only contains ASCII letters/digits (or underscores) for this to work correctly.

Comment: ive done this var regExp = new RegExp("/^(?!" + exclude + ")/i") and it currently hides everything, not just whats in exclude

Comment: If you use a string as a regex constructor, you must not use regex literal syntax. This means: `var regExp = new RegExp("^(?!" + exclude + ")", "i");`

Comment: Ah, I've just seen your edit. Well, `"Mobile | Fred" != "Fred"`, so the regex does exactly what you asked for. It matches all strings that are not equal to `"Fred"`. Do you want to exclude all strings that *contain* `"Fred"`? Would you differentiate between `Fred`, `Alfred` and `Fredo`?

Comment: maybe i should show this in a clearer view, its actually a search table, im gonna post it now...

Comment: its still not working :| the table is bringing them all back, is it bring them back because another cell contains the word? it shouldn't do that though, should it?

Comment: @AlexW: I can't judge your program's logic. My answer only shows how to match a string that doesn't contain a particular sub-regex. Have you tried printing the strings that your program fails on to see whether they contain more than you think?

Comment: im passing the string through, the string is Archived, i dont want to see archived results on page load, the searchtable function as above, all works apart from the exclude part :|

Answer (score 2):

You could populate a list of names you wish to match against:

```
var validNames = ['bob', 'bill'];
```

Then lowercase each input and match against the list:

```
if (validNames.indexOf(inputVal.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
    // it's a good name
}
```

For older browsers you have to shim [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

```
var re = new RegExp('^\\s*Fred\\s*$','i');
if (inputVal.match(re)) {
    // Fred has been found
} else {
    // Anything has been found
}
```